CKEditor styles not applying with my Tailwind website
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Project(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProjectCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = RichTextField(null=True)
    pdf  = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

I am using Tailwind CSS in my frontend, and I am displaying the project description {{project.description}}, but the styles I have added, why I filled the description with CKEditor didn't apply when I displayed the description in my Tailwind frontend how to fix that?

use this for show description:
{{project.description|safe}}

because of django is so much protected escape codes that is possible to made by hackers. If you are sure that is no danger for this use that code.
